# UI Design Issue

Tags: android, user-interface

I am new to Android. I am creating a layout for a registration form. Base container I am using as relative layout. Inside relative layout i am keeping liner layout container and then inside this all components of a registration form.

But after drooping two edit text field inside liner layout I can see both the edit text field are overlapping each other and it is visible as one and also moving towards center in liner container. Hope so understood. Well I need components one after one horizontally. Help?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/l_border"
            android:padding="30dp"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ll_border"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:hint="Enter Name"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ll_border"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:hint="Enter Mobile"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack" />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[[image: The layout look like this in editor]]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unless you want to add something over your inner `LinearLayout`, there is no point in nesting it inside the `RelativeLayout`.

Second, your inner `LinearLayout` has no orientation set, so by default is set to `horizontal` which means the first edit text (layout_width="match_parent") will push out of the screen the second EditText.

If you set the orientation for the inner LinearLayot, to "vertical", you will be able to see both fields.

If you want to have both edit texts, placed horizontally, set the `"layout_width"="0; "weight"="1` on both of the text fields. Or you can play around with the `RelativeLayout` positioning.

**UPDATE -- Suggested by @petey**

Here's a way to achieve what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  // this view is kind of pointless
android:background="@color/colorAccent"> 
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/l_border"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMobile"
        android:layout_width="0dp" // NOTICE THIS
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" // // NOTICE THIS
        android:background="@drawable/ll_border"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="0dp" // NOTICE THIS
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" // NOTICE THIS
        android:background="@drawable/ll_border"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:hint="Enter Mobile"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm digging this explanation.  But since the user is starting out could you improve this answer by adding a code block (to show them hows its done) below your summary? I think that would help them immensely

Comment: @petey Thx for suggestion, I've updated the answer, even though I'm not a fan of just copy/paste code :).

Comment: Thank You @petey for you kind attention, it worked!!

Comment: @danypata thank you for updating the answer...your suggestion worked.